# Javascript preferred way to organize object structure

Tags: javascript

I was curious as to what the standard or common way to organize large object structures was. My first reaction was to organize it like so:

```
GLOBAL = {
  child_1 : {
     obj_1 : null,
     obj_2 : null,
     func_1 : function () {
       //Stuff defined here....
     }
  },
  child_2 : {
     obj_1 : null,
     obj_2 : null,
     func_1 : function () { 
       //Stuff defined here....
     }
  },
  child_3 : {
    ....

};
```

This is pretty at first, but as the file grows larger and larger and functions get defined it becomes hard to read especially when functions have the same name, such as, "GLOBAL.child_1.func_1" and "GLOBAL.child_2.func_1".

Is there a standard way to structure large applications? One way I could keep it pretty I suppose is to define functions elsewhere and not inside the object hierarchy.

Comment: This whole thing seems odd to me. What kind of operations are you performing on it, or why would you have this many objects defined literally in a row?

Comment: I am developing a large application which requires a large object structure. Each object has different functions which are performed on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I struggle with this too.  Here are some blog posts that I find enlightening:

http://michaux.ca/articles/javascript-namespacing

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/#more-1789

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to put them all in one giant nested structure.  You can do:

```
var GLOBAL = {};

GLOBAL.child_1 = {
     obj_1 : null,
     obj_2 : null,
     func_1 : function () {
       //Stuff defined here....
     };

GLOBAL.child_2 = {
     obj_1 : null,
     obj_2 : null,
     func_1 : function () { 
       //Stuff defined here....
     };

GLOBAL.child_3 = {
    ....

};
```

Also, I don't understand why you're using generic names like child_1 and child_2.  If they have unique functions, then given them unique names that describes their function.  If they all have the same functions, then make a re-usable object that you can make multiple instances of.  If they're all identical and have no unique pre-declared data, then just initialize them all in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very interesting and its answer could be very complex. I will give you some links about that subject (some links refer to jQuery but this is not a limitation):

http://addyosmani.com/blog/large-scale-jquery/

http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/on-jquery-large-applications

Also, one tip I can give you is to separate your code using this pattern:

```
// file yoursite.somename.js
var GLOBAL = GLOBAL || {};
GLOBAL.somename = {
    someFunction: function() {}
    // [...]
};

// file yoursite.someothername.js
var GLOBAL = GLOBAL || {};
GLOBAL.someothername = {
    anotherFunction: function() {}
    // [...]
};
```

With that pattern, each functionality is separate into a single file, and each file add one key into the `GLOBAL` object. That object will be declared once and only once and will never be overridden.

Comment: Some other links that may be useful:
http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/
http://www.slideshare.net/SlexAxton/how-to-manage-large-jquery-apps
http://www.slideshare.net/rmurphey/building-large-jquery-applications